# Given that $C = I+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k B^k$, prove that $C^{-1} =B +I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A square matrix $B$ is such that $B^n=0$ for some positive integer $n$

Given that $C = I+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k B^k$, prove that $C^{-1} =B +I$

What I tried:

$C$

$= I+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k B^k$

$=I +(-B+B^2+...+(-1)^{n-1}B^{n-1})$

$=I+B^{-1} (-B^2+B^3+...+(-1)^{n-2}B^{n})$

$=I+B^{-1}B^{-1} (-B^3+B^4+...+(-1)^{n-3}B^{n})$

$=I+B^{-1}...B^{-1} (-B^n)$      basically $B^{-1}$ $ n-1$ times

$=I-B^{-1}$

$C=C^{-1}C-B^{-1}$

$C^{-1}C=C+B^{-1}$

$C^{-1}=I+C^{-1}B^{-1}$

So where did go wrong?

Comment: $B^{-1}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've assumed that $B$ is invertible; but, inherently, it can't be: if it was, there would be a matrix you could multiply the zero-matrix by to get the identity matrix.

To show that $C^{-1}=B+I$, we need only prove that $C(B+I)=I$. To that end:
$$
\begin{align*}
C(B+I)&=CB+CI\\
&=\left(I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^kB^k\right)B+\left(I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^kB^k\right)\\
&=B+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^kB^{k+1}+I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^kB^k\\
&=B+\sum_{k=2}^n(-1)^{k-1}B^k+I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^kB^k\\
&=I+B+(-B)+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(1-1)B^k+(-1)^{n-1}B^n\\
&=I,
\end{align*}
$$
since all other terms either cancel out or are zero to begin with.

Comment: Oh I assumed that $B^{-1} $ exists... but the qn said to prove $C^{-1} =I+B$ isn't verifying like not doing what the qn is asking for? At least that's what my teacher said that verifying is not proving

Comment: To prove that a matrix is invertible, it suffices to find a matrix which inverts it.  So, proving that $C(I+B)=I$ proves that $C$ is invertible AND that $C^{-1}=I+B$.

Comment: So technically we found $C^{-1} $ which is just given in the qn. All I had to do was just show that $C^{-1}C=I$ Ohhh Thanks a lot

Comment: But just another qn since we know that $C^{-1}$ exists. Can we say that $B^{-1}$ exists since $B=C^{-1} -I$ ?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi No, you cannot find one. The equation $B = C^{-1} -I$ does not say anything about the existence of $B^{-1}$. Actually $B$ is nilpotent, it cannot be invertible.

Comment: @xbh Great to know that. Thx for the interesting comment.

Answer (score 1):

Verify directly:
$$C(B+I)=(I+(-B)+(-B)^2+\cdots+(-B)^{n-1})(-(-B)+I)$$
Since $IB=BI$, apply $(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})(1-x)=1-x^n$,
$$C(B+I)=I-(-B)^n=I$$
therefore $C^{-1}=B+I$.